# Reverse the input in Chisel3

Tags: scala, reverse, chisel

I want to reverse the input signal in Chisel3. For instance, if the input is `12345678`, I want the output to be `87654321`. Can anyone please help me with this?

Code:

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
import chisel3.iotesters.{ChiselFlatSpec, Driver, PeekPokeTester}
import chisel3.util.Reverse

class Length extends Module {

val in     = Input(UInt(64.W))

val out    = Output(UInt(8.W))  

out := Reverse(in.x)
```

}

Comment: How about convert it to `String` and call `reverse` and then convert it back to number? As an example `12345.toString.reverse.toInt` will return `54321`

Comment: Throws the following error:  `type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int
[error]  required: chisel3.core.UInt
[error]   out = in.toString.reverse.toInt
[error]  `                          ^

Comment: Could you share your piece of code?

Comment: Hope it will help: `out = Output(UInt(in.getWidth.toString.reverse.toInt.W))`

Comment: `class Rev needs to be abstract, since method io in class LegacyModule of type => chisel3.core.Record is not defined`. If I change the class to abstract or trait it causes a lot of problems while instantiating

Comment: Sorry, I suspect my previous answer was incorrect. Try to use utility object `chisel3.util.Reverse`. Maybe it might help: `out := Reverse(in.x)`

Comment: It still shows the same error, Sir.

Comment: You need to implement `io` method iside `Length` class, as an example: `override def io: Record = IO(
    new Bundle {
      val in     = Input(UInt(64.W))
      val out    = Output(UInt(8.W))
      out := Reverse(in.x)
    }
  )`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir. Could you also please help me to write the test bench and driver for the same? It would be of great help

Comment: Sorry but according to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it would be better if you try to do it yourself, but if you are faced with some difficult problems you would ask here.

Comment: Okay, I will try, thank you

Answer (score 3):

The solution which was discussed in comments:

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util.Reverse

class Length extends Module {
  val io = IO(
    new Bundle {
      val in  = Input(UInt(64.W))
      val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
    }
  )
  io.out := Reverse(io.in)
}
```

Comment: This is almost correct but the assignment to out should not be in the Bundle move it outside of the io definition.

Comment: I edited @duelist's post which correctly shows the use of Reversed but moved  the assignment to be outside of the `io` declaration.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks, approved changes!

Comment: `out` and `in` need to be `io.out` and `io.in` in the connection, also `io.in` does not have a field `x`

Comment: The code works, but instead of the digits, the bits are getting reversed. Suppose I give my input as `19 = 00010011` I get a `200 = 11001000`. Can this be solved?